# SQL Server 2016 Licence

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

Hope you can help me out.

My current SQL setup is as following 
Two SQL Instances (2012 and 2016) stacked on a single virtual machine. With the SQL components SSRS and SSIS 2016 installed on same.

The only reason I did this was two lower licencing costs. My 2012 instance is primarily for older apps that aren't certified on SQL Server 2016. With the goal of moving all my databases over to SQL 2016.

My problem, I've had a request from a supplier for a  standalone virtual machine with SSRS 2016 installed for there reports only. I don't believe we are covered to install SQL components such as SSRS and SSIS on a separate virtual machine.

Any thoughts ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't allowed to give you licensing advice on here. Please contact Microsoft licensing instead. –

Comment: I can't speak for Microsoft and how they wish to license their product. But, you're welcome to install PostgreSQL 10 -- the latest and greatest -- on both of those virtual machines, the host that runs those virtual machines, your arm cell phone, and your grandmothers toaster. We're totally ok with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the following links may help you:

1. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing
2. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/microsoft-sql-server-licensing-simplified-into-7-rules/
3. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/09/first-concern-sql-virtualization-licensing/